# After I packaged it using pyinstaller, dxcam returned black screenshot images, How do I fix this?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

after I packaged it using pyinstaller, dxcam returned black screenshot images, How do I fix this?Before using pyinstaller, the program worked fine, but after using it, Dxcam only captured black images.

I've tried a number of things, including permission settings, etc., but it doesn't work.

Comment: `dxcam` was changed a year ago to make OpenCV support optional.  You may need to add `opencv-python` to the list of required packages for your installer run.